# Using os.sep in Python?

Tags: arcpy, python

What is os.sep and when should i use os.sep while scripting for arcgis ?

For example in below code i don't understand why should i use os.sep .

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

# Set the workspace for the ListFeatureClass function
#
env.workspace = "c:/base"

# Use the ListFeatureClasses function to return a list of 
#  all shapefiles.
#
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Copy shapefiles to a file geodatabase
#
for fc in fcList:
  arcpy.Copy_management(fc, "d:/base/output.gdb" + os.sep + fc.rstrip(".shp"))
```

Comment: Please note that this question is one of those "borderline" ones that is of (at best) marginal interest on a GIS site, because (a) it clearly has nothing special to do with the GIS program you're working with and (b) an obvious search on the Web immediately turns up an answer (Google "os.sep" for instance).  We're letting it stand because it has been answered and you're a relatively new user, but future questions meeting these criteria will be closed or migrated to a purely programming site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use os.path.join(), noting the caveat for Windows at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html. It takes care of the os.sep for you and makes your code more portable (not that ArcPy is portable, but in general).

```
for fc in fcList:
    arcpy.Copy_management(
        fc, os.path.join("d:/base/output.gdb", fc.rstrip(".shp")))
```

Comment: This is a good point.  Using os.path.join() is a better method for building paths.

Answer (score 4):

try this...

In your favourite python environment type:

```
import os
print os.sep
```

Your output will be '\'or '/' depending on the operating system you're using.

@artwork21's answer is more complete ;)  and beat me to the punch line!